# Indeterminate checkbox not working when filtered React MUI-Datatables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, mui-datatable

#### Info

I have a project that is using React, Redux, and [MUI-Datatables](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables). A simple demo for this project can be found at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sammet-uo7pb).

In this app, there are two main components, a map and a datatable. The two communicate via redux so that when a row is selected in the table, the respective circle in the map is highlighted and vice versa.

#### Problem

My problem is with the indeterminate toggle selectAll checkbox on the table. When the user has selected a row then applies a filter, the selectAll checkbox shows the '-' indeterminate symbol, but nothing happens when it is clicked.

#### Steps to recreate:

- User selects the first row in the table, circle1.
- User opens filter dialog in right-hand corner of table.
- From the Marker dropdown menu in the filter dialog, User selects circle3 as the filter value.
- User closes filter dialog
- User clicks on selectAll checkbox at the top of the select row column. It will be showing the '-' symbol.
- Notice that nothing changes. No rows are selected or deselected.

#### Desired Behavior:

When the User has selected a row in the table then applies a filter, the selectAll checkbox should still select all visible rows on first click and deselect all on second click the same way it normally would.

#### Code

*Live:*  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sammet-uo7pb)

*Table Component:*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { handleSelection } from "./redux";

import circles from "./assets/data/circles";

import { addToOrRemoveFromArray } from "./utils";

// Table component
const Table = ({ handleSelection, selections }) => {
  const [selectionIndexes, setSelectionIndexes] = useState([]);

  // When 'selections' changes in redux store:
  useEffect(() => {
    let indexes = [];
    // Iterate selections:
    selections.forEach((selection) => {
      // Push the index of the selected
      // circle into index arr:
      let index = circles.indexOf(selection);
      indexes.push(index);
    });
    // Set selections to local state hook:
    setSelectionIndexes(indexes);
  }, [selections]);

  // Table options:
  const options = {
    rowsSelected: selectionIndexes, // User provided array of numbers (dataIndexes) which indicates the selected rows
    selectToolbarPlacement: "none",
    selectableRows: "multiple", // Enable selection of multiple rows
    setRowProps: (row, dataIndex, rowIndex) => {
      return {
        style: {
          padding: ".5rem",
          margin: ".5rem auto"
        }
      };
    },
    // When a row(s) is/are selected:
    onRowSelectionChange: (
      currentRowsSelected,
      allRowsSelected,
      rowsSelected
    ) => {
      let temp = [];
      let indexes = [];
      // Iterate rowsSelected:
      rowsSelected.forEach((row) => {
        // Add or remove row index to/from indexes arr:
        indexes = addToOrRemoveFromArray(row, indexes, "indexes");
        // Circle data:
        let circle_data = circles[row];
        // Add or remove circle_data to/from temp arr:
        temp = addToOrRemoveFromArray(circle_data, temp, "temp");
      });
      // Set indexes to local hook:
      setSelectionIndexes(indexes);
      // Send the circle data to redux:
      handleSelection(temp);
    }
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      name: "marker",
      label: "Marker",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false
      }
    },
    {
      name: "lat",
      label: "Latitude",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false
      }
    },
    {
      name: "lon",
      label: "Longitude",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false
      }
    },
    {
      name: "radius",
      label: "Radius",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false
      }
    }
  ];

  const table_name = `Circle Markers`;

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: "table", tableLayout: "fixed", width: "100%" }}>
        <MUIDataTable
          title={<h3>{table_name}</h3>}
          data={circles}
          columns={columns}
          options={options}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    selections: state.selection.selections
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleSelection: (selections) => dispatch(handleSelection(selections))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Table);
```

How can I get the selectAll checkbox to work properly when a row outside of the filtered data has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok to de-select the selected row when filters applied? I did a workaround to meet the desired behavior.

Live Code: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-hooks-f6e6b)

I added additional code in **Table.jsx line 34**

```
onFilterChange: (changedColumn, changedColumnIndex, displayData) => {
  changedColumnIndex.forEach((data, key) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length) {
      setSelectionIndexes([]);
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: That is one solution, but it, unfortunately, does not fit what I need. I need for the row outside of the filters to stay selected and for it to be togglable from the selectAll checkbox while the filters are applied. [React-tables](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/kitchen-sink) has the functionality, but I really like MUI Datatables and have already down a lot of work customizing it for my project, so I'd rather not switch .

Comment: I see. Did you try to add the selected row on filters whenever it was open? Maybe that could work.